# Some beginner questions about how to port a CRUD application to PhalconPHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, nginx, phalcon

I just started to use PhalconPHP 1.3.1 for an app for my studies' master thesis. Isnt totally developed but I'm working on the CRUD for the moment, so after have some functionality and the UI working I decided to start to introduce this amazing framework. I'm was new on web development, MVC and ORM patterns till I started this thesis. It's first time I use template engines as well. For now I'm successful porting all, but I'm afraid that I'm not doing it in the right way. I started adding my code to the PhalconPHP bootstrap created with the dev tools. Now I start with the questions:

1º- As is a web app that In the future I'll wrap with Phonegapp, I'm using AJAX load function, to don't load all the menu and libraries every time that the id = "content"change. For this I use $('#content').load(); for the content and historyjs functions to change the URL. I didn't do any change to the original code apart of configure on Nginx the clean URLs as

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
```

In the documentation shows different way of using AJAX, so I'm afraid that I shouldn't be using this way, breaking somehow the MVC pattern.

2º-Related with this I add to the AJAX dynamically load URL a variable ?header=yes that indicates me to just load the content. So for this in every controller, in the indexActions I do:

```
$header = filterinput(INPUTGET, 'header');

$this->view->setVar("header",$header);
```

And after I just check with volt the variable. Is it the right way? I thought to do all with volt but I haven't found how to.

3º-Also, because the menu is common to every page, in the main index.volt(in the folder view) I include the menu depending on the variable. Is it OK as well? Or should I move it to the different views?

4º-Because of 1º, I made my own click functions where I push a new URL and load the content, once again I'm affraid I'm breaking good practices of Phalcon.

5º-The JS/HTML part is in plain code for now, I just replace the PHP part with volt syntax. Should I replace as well code like

```
<link href="../css/stylefile.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

For its volt syntax?

I would like you to clarify me and give suggestions in case of need of how to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Phalcon and volt at the moment for a commercial project and I find new ways to do things all the time, you have to really try out different methods and see if it works for what you need. if you are looking to work on multiple devices with the same data I would look at the phalcon micro version and use that as a rest api and then create another project which uses the phalcon mvc version to do the client side rendering then use ajax to get the data from your phalcon micro project. This way if you go native mobile, desktop, tv, tablet whatever your needs you don't have to rewrite your code you just need to create a new frontend.

Another thing to look into are partials, you can separate out your header, footer and navigation inside a partial and call them like so:

```
{{ partial("partials/layout/footer") }}
```

You also want to look at creating a proper rest api url structure for your phalcon micro project. if you want to get all users you can do something like `/users` and to get a user by id you can do `/users/1` that is very very basic so I have copied in a great article below to give you more information on rest api and a good structure.

You can also set volt variable like so:

```
$this->view->header = $header;
```

and call it like so:

```
{{ header }}
```

I hope this gives you a little idea, but just try it out and read some articles from different blogs to get an idea what other people are doing, the Phalcon forum and IRC channel is also a really good place to get help

**Some good articles and resources**

http://inmensosofa.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/look-into-various-rest-apis.html
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/micro.html

Comment: Thankyou for your information, but still didnt help so much to my doubts:

Comment: At first my app isnt native, is Hybrid. So it's plain html/css/js responsive(same ui code) and almost same code besides phonegap's webview. The small differences are controlled client side.

Comment: About the partials I just don't use them for two reasons, first include are most efficient because are precompiled, second I plan to minimize the client code(erasing spaces and comments for production) so for use this toguether with phalcon cache you must do it in plain HTML. About the volt variables I already knew about that. Anyway I'm quite new on web developing world, so I'll save the suggestion for native apps with phalcon. I still didnt play with ORM so I'll stick to your suggestion about the url once I arrive to that point. Thankyou very much ;)